# Как создать событие в нативном js

Tags: javascript, события

```
<input id="name" type="text"  placeholder="Ваш имя">
```

как на чистом js создать событие

```
theName = document.getElementById('name')

theName.value = 'jon'
```

и когда **theName** изменяться значение **value** на *jon* то вызывается **callback**

Comment: Зачем Вам создавать событие, если есть готовые: `input`, `change`, `blur` - выбирайте любое подходящее

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Можно просто после присваивания вызвать нужную функцию

Answer (score -2):

ну вы даете сразу бы так сказали!

```
<input id="name" type="text"  placeholder="Ваш имя">

ngOnInit(){
    let inp: any = fromEvent(document.getElementById('name'), 'keyup');
    inp.subscribe(val=>{
        if(val.target.value == 'jon'){
            this.someFunc();
        }
    })
}

someFunc(){
    console.log('someFunc');
}
```

или https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e25fzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: не правильно поняли вопрос, console.log('called') выводится в консоль при вводе в консоль вот этого  theName.value = 'jon'

Comment: а как надо вам?

Comment: вот так теперь?

Comment: при вводе в консоль theName.value = 'jon' срабатывает someCallBack то есть динамически

Comment: что вы имеете в виду говоря при вводе в консоль и theName.value = 'jon' это полностью строка или это условие вообще не понятно. Можете вопрос правильно задать?

Comment: был theName.value равен  ""   и вдруг стал равен 'jon' динамически , то-есть прилетело значение  не важно откуда и какой тип данных , и должна сработать функция someCallBack , в angular это называется observer или listener